# Adding both an animated css change and an append on hover using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I may not even be using the word "events" correctly. Here's what I want to do:

I have a link that starts off with the words "Read More". When a user hovers over the "Ream More" link to click on it, I'd like the padding on the right to expand a bit and then contract when the hovering stops. I can do that pretty easily with this:

```
$('#post-text a.more-link').hover(
function(){$(this).animate({paddingRight: '18px'}, 200);},        
function(){$(this).animate({paddingRight: '4px'}, 200);});
```

But I also want to append the text ", Please" when you hover over it as well. I can do that using `.append()` but I kind of run into a snag. If I add it to the code like this:

```
$('#post-text a.more-link').hover(
function(){$(this).animate({paddingRight: '18px'}, 200), $(this).append(", Please");},        
function(){$(this).animate({paddingRight: '4px'}, 200);});
```

Then every time someone hovers it adds another ", Please". I only want to add it once, on the first hover if possible.

Additionally, I'd like the ", Please" to stay there and not leave when they stop hovering. I'm guessing I'm going to need to use `.one()` or `.bind()` but I'm not sure where that's supposed to go.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I made some progress, see below:

First of all, I just learned how to finally user `.one()` and I also just learned that `.hover()` works in the same method as `mouseenter`. So here's what I have that works now:

```
$('#post-text a.more-link').one('mouseenter', function() {
$(this).append(", Please");});
```

So I'm happy with that, I just need to figure out how add both that and the padding animation for a little more flare.

Answer (score 1):

```
use $(this).append(' <span class="whatever">Please</span>');});

and on mouseout $(this).remove('.whatever');
```

use rather :

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#sall").live("mouseover mouseout", function(event) {
      if ( event.type == "mouseover" ) {
        $(this).append('Please');
      } else { 
          var g = $(this).html();
         $(this).html(g.substr(0,g.length-"Please".length)); //get rid of please
      }
});

})
```

see this example http://jsfiddle.net/jECW5/

Comment: I could do that, but I wouldn't want to remove my span on mouseout and if I didn't remove it and someone hovered over it again they would get another please, which actually sounds really fun with a bunch of pelases in a row but it just wouldn't be functional :)

Comment: see my updated answer... I put "Please".length but if your string is always the same you can calculate yourself once, so the script to have less to do